# XCode Compiler Apple LLVM 3.1 vs LLVM GCC 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, image-processing, opencv, opticalflow

I downloaded this project to give it a try (http://www.hatzlaha.co.il/150842/Lucas-Kanade-Detection-for-the-iPhone). It also has a released version on AppStore.

When I downloaded the source and compiled, it gave compilation errors. I changed the compiler to LLVM GCC and it instantly compiled without any errors or warnings.

Further here is what I did:

- Downloaded the app Lucas Kanade on personal iPhone. Runs as expected (ie. shows tracked points and video output).
- Deployed the above compiled app on company iPad. Here is shows the tracked points (which means the application is getting the video frames) but not able to display the video output.

General app flow:

- Grab a frame from the camera.
- Process the frame (track points).
- Output the frame, so the screen looks like its showing the camera feed, as expected.

Device details:

- iPhone: OS 5.1.1 (9B206); iPhone 4;
- iPad: OS 5.1 (9B176); iPad 2;

**Questions**

- Is the video output problem occurring because of the different in OS versions or because of the GCC compiler being used?
- If it is the compiler problem, would be be appropriate to put the compile errors here for resolution or do I need to start a separate Question?

I know this info might not be enough since there are a lot of unknowns, but trust me, getting into the details of the app would be a really exhaustive problem description. Let me know what more info is needed to guess the solution. I'll update it here.

Answer (score 0):

Like you already said the info is not enough. I can just guess. The projects for tracking points uses generally their own driver for camera access. The reason, why it does not work with llvm compiler, might be that.

Just look in the project if you find any file specific to iPhone. They are mostly dat files. And maybe you find some preprocessor macros in the project like #ifdef target_iphone something like that. In that case you can contact the producer and request the driver for iPad.

I did not download and tried the project, but it is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but the project seems to be using standard drivers. I found these lines in the code.             

AVCaptureSession *session = [self session];
            AVCaptureDeviceInput *newVideoInput = [[AVCaptureDeviceInput alloc] initWithDevice:[self backFacingCamera] error:nil];

AVFoundation framework is also included in the project. These lines lead me to believe that it is using standard drivers and should work on both iPhone and iPad. Correct?

Comment: Maybe a wrong setting in opencv? For example screen resolution? While initializing the engine(openCV), it should set some params or read from a settings file.

Comment: Some more curious things I came across in the last 1 hr.

 - I can't find any OpenCV code in the project (sounds silly, I know). No OpenCV framework, or source files.
 - I downloaded the App from the AppStore on the iPad, it shows the video output, as expected. This leads me to believe some local factor is affecting the project (**maybe** compilation).

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion, it is an OpenCV-based project since, the objective of the application is to demonstrate Lucas Kanade Optical Flow. Also, I can see functions like cvGoodFeaturesToTrack and cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK, which are OpenCV functions. Just that I cannot see where the library binaries are or where these headers are located.

Comment: Did you try to change resolution in MyVideoBuffer.mm file initWithSession method?
Since iPad 2 supports that resolution should not help but try.

Comment: There's no concept of a "driver" on iOS, especially within an application. Apple's AV Foundation framework is used to access the camera in all such applications on these devices.

Comment: @ameyazing -  The OpenCV libraries are incorporated in this project as precompiled static libraries for either Simulator or device that are then linked in. See the `opencv_device` and `opencv_simulator` directories for where these are located.